# $\Lambda f(x)=\alpha(x)f(x)$ is not compact unless $\alpha\equiv 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

**Question**

For a fixed $\alpha\in C([-\pi,\pi];\mathbb{C})$ define the map $\Lambda:(L^2[-\pi,\pi];\mathbb{C})\rightarrow L^2([-\pi,\pi];\mathbb{C})$ by $$\Lambda(f)(x):=\alpha(x)f(x).$$

Show that $\Lambda$ is not compact unless $a \equiv 0$.

**Attempt**
The following is surely too straightforward to be correct:

If $\alpha \neq 0$ then $\|\alpha\|_{L^2}>0$ and $M=\max_{x\in [\pi,\pi]}{\alpha^2(x)}>0$. Consider the orthogonal sequence $\{e^{inx}\}$. Then for distint $m,n$,
\begin{align*}
\|\Lambda e^{inx}-\Lambda e^{imx}\|&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\alpha^2(x)(e^{inx}-e^{imx})\overline{(e^{inx}-e^{imx})} \ dx\\&=2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\alpha^2 \ dx-\int_{\pi}^{\pi}\alpha^2(x)(e^{i(n-m)x}+e^{i(m-n)x})\ dx\\
&\geq 2\|\alpha\|-M\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{i(n-m)x}+e^{i(m-n)x} \ dx\\
&=2\|\alpha\|>0.
\end{align*}

Thus we have exhibited a bounded sequence for which the image contains no convergent subsequence. So $\Lambda$ can't be compact.

Comment: The third step in your inequality is incorrect. You'd need to take absolute values in the remaining integral but then it does vanish anymore

Comment: But you have the right idea, use an ortho normal basis, but an even easier one: try to look at appropriately scaled indicator functions of l increaingly small disjoint intervals clustering towards some value of x for which $\alpha $ is not zero.

Comment: @Bananach could you expand on this just a bit more? I am having trouble constructing this sequence

Comment: Let's say $\alpha (0) > 0$. Then the functions $ 2^n1_{[2^{-n},2^{-n+1}]} $ are orthonormal and their images under $\Lambda $...